# white lines on heat map made by ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

Look at the following picture, I tried to get a heat plot with ggplot2, but there is a white vertical line on it. What happens? Anybody gives me an hint?
Besides, there is a white line on each side of plot, why couldn't the heat plot fill the whole part while the contour fill the whole part?

[image]

Comment: Consider exporting the figure first. Use `ggsave`. Does this line appear in vector (pdf) and raster (png) formats?

Comment: @Roman Luštrik, the line still appears there. But the horizontal position has changed.

Comment: Ok, without a reproducible example there's little we can do. Have you tried updating the relevant packages? Have you turned R off and on again?

Comment: @Roman Luštrik, I've tried the same code on different pc and relevant packages have been updated but nothing changes. Besides, the white line doesn't appear in the zoom window and if I don't set any theme, there is no white line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lucky! I've sovled the problem with setting an ultra-small left or right margin.